# How do i get the part of the url in php

Tags: php

How do I get Last 3 parts of the url

For example , I have link like below

```
http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink.pdf
```

I will get the last part of the url using below code

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink.pdf";
echo $end = end((explode('/', $url)));
```

But i need last 3 parts from the url like below

```
/two/three/drink.pdf
```

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Strange question... if you use ``explode()`` anyway to slip the path components apart, then why can't you simply use the last three elements you get returned?

Comment: If `http://www.yoursite/one` remains constant in your URL then you can use `echo ('http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink.pdf',23);` where 23 is the length of `http://www.yoursite/one` which you want to omit.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php in combination with http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink.pdf";
    $ex = explode('/', $url);

    $arr = array_slice($ex, -3, 3);
    $output = '/'.implode('/', $arr);
    var_dump($output);    // Outputs /two/three/drink.pdf
```

First, you use `explode` to break the `url` string into an `array`. Then use `array_slice` to get the last three elements of the array and finally `implode` to glue back the array elements using `/` as the glue.

**Putting it all in one line would look like:**

```
echo '/'.implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $url), -3, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink.pdf";
$url_array = (explode('/', $url));
print_r(array_slice($url_array,-3,3));
```

Hope this helps.